# Divide matrix values by category means in R

Tags: r, matrix, categories, transformation

I have a matrix *(A)* containing 211 rows and 6 columns (one per time period) and a different matrix *(B)* containing 211 rows and 2 columns, the second of which contains categorial information (1-9).

My aim is to create a new matrix *(C)* where each value in matrix A is the *value(A) divided by the mean of (value(A) by category(B))*. I managed to compute the means for each category per column with the aggregate function. These are stored in a separate dataframe, *column_means*, with each time wave in a separate column. This also contains the information about the group in *column_means[,1]*.

I don't understand how to proceed from here and am looking for an elegant solution so I can transfer this knowledge to future projects (and possibly improve my existing code). My guess is that the solution is hidden somewhere in dplyr and rather simple once you know it.

Thank you for any suggestions.

Data example:

```
##each column here represents a wave:
initialmatrix <- structure(c(0.882647671948723, 0.847932241438909, 0.753052308699317, 
0.754977233408875, NA, 0.886095543329695, 0.849625252682829, 
0.78893884364632, 0.77111113840682, NA, 0.887255207679895, 0.851503493865384, 
0.812107856411831, 0.793982699495818, NA, 0.885212452552841, 
0.854894065774315, 0.815265718290737, 0.806766276556325, NA, 
0.882027335190646, 0.85386634818439, 0.818052477777012, 0.815997781565393, 
NA, 0.88245957310107, 0.855819521951304, 0.830425687228663, 0.820857689847061, 
NA), .Dim = 5:6, .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("V1", "V2", "V3", "V4", 
"V5", "V6")))

##the first column is unique ID, the 2nd the category:
categories <- structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 4L), .Dim = c(5L, 
2L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("V1", "V2")))

##the first column represents the category, column 1-6 the mean per category for each corresponding wave in "initialmatrix"
column.means <- structure(list(Group.1 = 1:5, x = c(0.805689153058216, 0.815006230419524, 
0.832326976776262, 0.794835253329865, 0.773041961434791), asset_means_2...2. = c(0.80050960343197, 
0.81923553710203, 0.833814773618545, 0.797834687980729, 0.780028077018158
), asset_means_3...2. = c(0.805053341257357, 0.828691564900149, 
0.833953165695685, 0.799381078569563, 0.785813047374534), asset_means_4...2. = c(0.806116664276125, 
0.832439754757116, 0.835982197159582, 0.801702200401293, 0.788814840753852
), asset_means_5...2. = c(0.807668548993891, 0.83801834926905, 
0.836036508152776, 0.803433961863399, 0.79014026195926), asset_means_6...2. = c(0.808800359101212, 
0.840923947682599, 0.839660313992458, 0.804901773257962, 0.793165113115977
)), row.names = c(NA, 5L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Can you add a minimal example (data, code you tried etc) to make your problem reproducible?

Comment: Of course, Markus - sorry, I thought the problem was simple enough but in hindsight reproducible examples are always the wiser choice. Like I said, I'm at a loss at how to proceed - I can hardly find a way to start solving the problem, so I'll have to disappoint you regarding the code I've tried so far, although I'm still doing research as we speak.

Comment: Is there a reason for you to be using matrices instead of dataframes? It seems that if you started from a single dataframe of 7 columns, it could easily be solved using dplyr.

Comment: I am open to a solution using df's and dplyr, Lamia - sure! I'll just transform them back right after. The reason I'm using matrices is that the library I'm using (RSiena) requires the matrix format to read in covariates.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you have 3 categories: 1,2 and 4. So for example, for Category 2 which has 3 rows, what do you want to normalize the value (0.8826477) in col 1 row 1 in A by? In other words, what is your expected output?

Comment: Cheers Lamia, I actually have 9 categories, but I capped the example after row 5. I want to have each value in my initial matrix divided by the mean of its category. My object "initialmatrix" has 211 unique IDs - these correspond to the "categories" variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are trying to do?

```
options(digits=3)
divisor <- column.means[categories[, 2], -1]
divisor
#         x asset_means_2...2. asset_means_3...2. asset_means_4...2. asset_means_5...2. asset_means_6...2.
# 2   0.815              0.819              0.829              0.832              0.838              0.841
# 1   0.806              0.801              0.805              0.806              0.808              0.809
# 2.1 0.815              0.819              0.829              0.832              0.838              0.841
# 2.2 0.815              0.819              0.829              0.832              0.838              0.841
# 4   0.795              0.798              0.799              0.802              0.803              0.805
initialmatrix/divisor
#         x asset_means_2...2. asset_means_3...2. asset_means_4...2. asset_means_5...2. asset_means_6...2.
# 2   1.083              1.082              1.071              1.063              1.053              1.049
# 1   1.052              1.061              1.058              1.061              1.057              1.058
# 2.1 0.924              0.963              0.980              0.979              0.976              0.988
# 2.2 0.926              0.941              0.958              0.969              0.974              0.976
# 4      NA                 NA                 NA                 NA                 NA                 NA
```

Comment: Thank you - this worked flawlessly. I'm going with this solution for now.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a job for Superma ... no wait ... `map2`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

as_tibble(initialmatrix) %>%
  mutate(category = as.double(as_tibble(categories)$V2),
         across(starts_with('V'), 
                ~ unlist(map2(., category, ~ .x/mean(c(.x, .y)))))) %>%
  select(-category)

#       V1     V2     V3     V4     V5     V6
#    <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
# 1  0.612  0.614  0.615  0.614  0.612  0.612
# 2  0.918  0.919  0.920  0.922  0.921  0.922
# 3  0.547  0.566  0.578  0.579  0.581  0.587
# 4  0.548  0.557  0.568  0.575  0.580  0.582
# 5  NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA
```

Comment: Thank you, rjen. Unfortunately, I get the following error: ```Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `..2`.
x Mapped vectors must have consistent lengths:
* `.x` has length 211
* `.y` has length 422
ℹ Input `..2` is `across(...)`.

Now obviously, 422 is twice as much as 211 so I'm guessing it multiplies categories * the number of columns (2)? Also thanks for suggesting the map2 function. Handy stuff, I'm reading into it.

Comment: @SteffenT: You are very welcome. My solution works consistently for me when I use the example data. 1) Does my solution work with the example data on your end? 2) If yes, I guess we should look for discrepancies between your data and the example data you have provided.

Comment: It does work with the example so indeed, there must be discrepancies. dcarlsons answer (above) worked for me, so I'll leave it at that but shall read into map2 when I'm facing more issues of the sort. Thanks again!